# Can many servers communicate with one client on one socket?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming

On the client side:

```
    int clientSocketFD;
    if ((clientSocketFD = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("socket (): ");
        exit (1);
    }
```

The client is one and servers are many. Do I have to issue the socket() system call each time a new server needs to get connected to the same client?

Please explain WHY.

Comment: downvoters: I am not a mind reader. explain the reasons so that the question is improved.

Comment: *Research Effort*. Any tutorial or text on sockets would answer your question; yes, in order to talk to a server, you have to open a connection to it.

Comment: @BrianRoach If that is the reason for the downvote, then you need to know that such simple questions are permitted on SO. About the code snippet: If I knew better I would not have asked this. BTW, I am not a mind reader.

Comment: I agree that the fact that multiple sockets are needed can be easily researched. However, the WHY is far more intricate. Because she asked why, I believe it is a decent question. I remember trying to grasp the concept of a socket when I first started. Here is the best tutorial I know of (it does not explain the WHY of this question however): http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Comment: @jowo Actually I was interested in WHY. The "answer" in yes or no can be found by compiling the program, but the compiler won't tell the reasons.

Comment: Note that the need for multiple socket() calls on the client side is a restriction of the socket() API, not something inherent in TCP/IP itself. TCP would be perfectly happy to have multiple connections using the same client address/port, as long as they're going to different servers (since the TCP connection is uniquely identified by the client IPaddr/port,server IPaddr/port combination). It would be possible to have connect() work like accept() (create a new connection with the same port #), but that's not how the BSD sockets API (and all that emulate it) happened to be designed.

Comment: @DavidGelhar See if you can put that as a detailed answer. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - you need one socket for each connection.

A socket is a client IP address + client port + server IP address + server port combination. If a client is talking to multiple servers, it is using multiple ports on the client machine.

Each time you connect() a socket, you are allocating a new port.

You can specify what client port you want to use by bind()-ing to the port number. Otherwise, the operating system chooses a port for you. This is called an "ephemeral" port.

If a server is talking to multiple clients, there is a socket created for each client by the call to accept().

An analogy that I remember:

Imagine that you have an apartment building with many people living in it. There are mailboxes available out front for the people in the apartment to use.

The apartment building corresponds to a computer, the people in the apartment correspond to programs running on the computer, and the mailboxes are ports. Each port can be used by only one application at a time as its private in/out box.

A socket is a link between a single mailbox on one building to a single mailbox on another. It is the "to" and "from" address. The socket API uses a socket to know where to send packets, and what reply address to put on the packet. A socket may even link two mailboxes on the same building.

A single application on the computer may be using many ports, and they may even be connected to the same port on the same remote computer. Therefore the socket information (IP address + port on *both* connected machines) is needed to eliminate any ambiguity over the destination and return addresses.

Likewise multiple applications on a single computer may be connected to the same port on the same server and sending requests, but the server sends its response to the right application because the return addresses have different port numbers.

A socket has the same 4 pieces of information on both communicating machines.

In client/server communication for a Web server, many clients are connected to one server port. So the sockets all look like { client(n) IP, client(n) port, server IP, server port 80 }.

As @DavidGelhar said it would theoretically be possible for multiple servers to be communicating with the same port on the client, because the socket information specifies the correct server address to send to. However you cannot connect() a single port multiple times. The servers could all connect() to that same client port, but then they can no longer be called servers :)

Basically, a socket is just a 4-piece data structure that the socket API uses to know where to send data to, and what return address to put on the data. Likewise a "port" is just a number used as an address to target a specific application on a machine, it is by no means an actual hardware object.

Comment: If you dont' explicitly inform about the edits, people won't get the notifications.

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP (which `SOCK_STREAM` uses) is a 1-to-1 connection between client and server. You need a new `socket()` call for each new connection you want to make.